# Only allow merge when certain user reviewed the code in Gerrit Code Review

Tags: git, gerrit

We're using the code-review label in Gerrit (not the verified label) to handle all approvals. We'd like to configure the permissions so that a patch can only be merged when a certain user has signed off on the patch. Is there a way to do this without having to use any new labels?

The idea is that merges can only occur when either the project owner or build user has given a code-review +2.

Comment: Is there any reason to give any other users +2 permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Grant "Label Code-Review -2 +2" at Projects > List > *project_name* > Access only to the "Project Owners" and the build user. Grant "Label Code-Review -1 +1" to the others members of the project.

Comment: This implies that we can merge a patch before someone in the team has reviewed it. Ideally that's not what you want....

Comment: If you want to have two type of approvals (1. "review" and 2. "signed off") you need to have to labels for that (1. "Code-Review" and 2. "Sign-Off"). It's impossible to have just one label and control two different kind of approvals.